# Error show for installing a package like jquery,angularjs using npm.

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I find error in installing the packages of npm in windows 10.
[This is the screenshot of errors showing in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xdiv.png)

I have already installed node.js and npm. It works fine and show the version of these. But problem occurs in installing the packages of npm.

Comment: The error suggests you might be behind a proxy. Are you?

Answer (score -1):

Try  using a CDN instead of installing jQuery or AngularJS . It helps in faster loading of its features and saves space on your computer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.